# variables scope in php losses and foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have some code. When I try to return $language[0] =>all ok. But when I try to return  $language[1] => this element not find. Please tell me how to change this code

```
function language($id)
{
            $language = array();
            $criteria = array("id" => $id);
            $fields = array('language');

            $cursor = $collection->find($criteria, $fields);

            foreach ($cursor as $row) {
                $language[0] = $row['language'];

            }


            $criteria = array("id" => $language[0]);
            $fields = array('lang');

            $cursor2 = $collection->find($criteria, $fields);
            foreach ($cursor2 as $row) {
                $language[1] = $row['lang'];
            }
            return $language[1];
}
```

Comment: try doing foreach($cursor as $row) { $language[] = $row['language'] instead. You are overwriting the value over and over atm.

Comment: It seems to me the problem (one of the problems...) is `$collection` as that variable is not defined in the current scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `[0]`

```
$language[0] = $row['language'];  // overwritting subscript 0
```

So it becomes

```
$language[] = $row['language']; // adding to index
```

Also the `$collection` is not defined.